# What kind of transformation is the composition?

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, rotations, reflection

Let $A = (-1,-1)$, $B = (3,2)$ and $C = (11,4)$ be points of the euclidean plane.

(a) Give the equattion of the line $C$ in Hesse normal form and calculate the diastance between $B$ and the line $AC$.

(b) Give the reflection $\sigma$ to the line $AC$ in analytic form.

(c) Let $\tau$ be the reflection at the line $AB$ and $\rho$ the reflection at the line $BC$. What linear trnaformation is $\sigma\circ\tau$ and $\sigma\circ\tau$ and $\sigma\circ\tau\circ\rho$ (translation, rotation or similar) ? Justify your answer.

$$$$

I have done (a) and (b).

For (c) I have done the following:

The lines $AC$ and $AB$ intersect in $A$.

The composition of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ is then a rotation around the intersection point, i.e. $A$, with angle $2\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $AB$ and$AC$.

The composition of $\sigma$, $\tau$ and $\rho$, i.e. the composition of a rotation and a reflection is a reflection.

Is that correct? How can we justify that further?

Comment: In part (a) is there a typo? Because you start by saying $C$ is a point, and then part (a) refers to "the line $C$." Also what is Hesse normal form of a line?

Comment: $\sigma \circ \tau \circ \rho$ is not a reflection, but a glide reflection. Aside: The amount of glide is exactly the circumference of the orthic triangle of $ABC$.